# Looking for 4D noise generator

Tags: javascript, maps

I am looking for a 4D noise generator in order to create wrapping random surfaces. I have 2D and 3D generators [here](https://gist.github.com/banksean/304522), but I cannot find a similar generator for 4D which I just can call as

```
var value = noise4D(x,y,z,w);
```

in javascript.

Maybe there are other idea how to create a random surface heightmap which is wrapped on itself (to create a smooth rotating sphere with a random heightmap)?